# How to write response/variables to a particular cell of xlsx excel file using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, apache-poi, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins, jmeter-5.0

I want to write jmeter response to a excel file at particular cell.
I have kept tika jar in jmeter lib/ext folder but when I open Jmeter I get below errors
[image: jmeter console error]

Please let me know how can I overcome this error or are there any other apache POI libraries which I can use?
Thanks

EDIT: I have freshly installed the Jmeter and that error is no more now thanks @Dmitri. I'm using "tika-app-2.6.0.jar" at lib folder I have below code in my beanshell sampler
[image: Beanshell code]

but I'm getting below error when trying to run
[image: View result tree]

Can someone help?
Thanks

Comment: Why are you adding the Apache Tika App jar, which is intended for standalone use? Why aren't you adding the specific Tika jars and dependencies you want?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a [Jar Hell](https://dzone.com/articles/what-is-jar-hell), i.e. you have several instances of [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/) libraries in your [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath) and the [Java Classloader](https://www.baeldung.com/java-classloaders) picks the wrong .jar combination.

Also "lib/ext" folder is for JMeter Plugins, all the dependency .jar files should go to "lib" folder.

And last but not the least [according to JMeter Best Practices you should always be using the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version) so consider

1. Performing clean installation of [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5) (or whatever is the latest stable JMeter version which is available at [JMeter Downloads page](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi))
2. Make sure that only one instance of Apache POI library is in JMeter Classpath ("lib" folder of your JMeter installation)
3. Restart JMeter to pick up the POI .jar(s). You can also use tika-app.jar but in that case make sure not to add anything else as Tika has POI bundled.
4. The error should go away